# Service Now Integration - How to create Outbound REST message with HTTP method by using API/TableAPI

Tags: rest, servicenow, outbound

```
const newMessage = {
  "name": "PushChangesToServicePortal_TEST",
  "sys_name": "PushChangesToServicePortal_TEST",
  "rest_endpoint": "XXXX-api",
};

let createMessageRes = await post(RESOURCE_URL, newMessage, {"Authorization": auth});
```

I'm able to create outbound REST Message using this code. How can I add/create HTTP method into it using table API?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate javascript code for the request you want with "Rest API Explorer" in "System web services" in SNOW. How to article here:

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/task/t_GetStartedAccessExplorer.html

Documentation of the API is here:

https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=newyork&id=r_TableAPI-GET